# Image scrolling twice in jquery carouFredSel-5.6.4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having two issues with my website code.

Link: http://coding.designzzz.com/demos/bakery-site/

First with my slider right arrow click it will scroll 2 images at a time. I only want it to scroll 1 image at a time.

Second- In Chrome my slider does not work properly. It seems to have some height issue and is not properly visible.

Please give me some suggestions that might help fix my problems.

Comment: The height seems to be set with JS, which is coming from that plugin. To be honest I would just write my own slider.